# i'm beginner in c++ and i can't understand blob coloring's result while i'm studying recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

the result said that

```
<Original image>
.................
.9999...9.....9..
99....99999.99999
.9999...9.....9..
<Labelled image>
.................
.1111...2.....3..
11....22222.33333
.1111...2.....3..
```

like this.

i can understand the original image but can't Labelled image. i mean is it supposed to be all 3? not including 1,2.
actually i don't understand well about what i just named label function

code

```
#include <cstdio>
#define WIDTH 17
#define HEIGHT 5
void label(unsigned char img[HEIGHT][WIDTH], int x, int y, int color)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= WIDTH || y >= HEIGHT || img[y][x] != 9)
        return;
    img[y][x] = color;
    label(img, x-1, y, color);
    label(img, x, y-1, color);
    label(img, x+1, y, color);
    label(img, x, y+1, color);
}
void blobColoring(unsigned char img[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    int color = 1;
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
    {
        if (img[y][x] == 9)
            label(img, x, y, color++);
    }
}
void printImage(unsigned char img[HEIGHT][WIDTH], char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for(int x =0; x<WIDTH; x++)
        {
            if (img[y][x] == 0) printf(".");
            else printf("%d", img[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void main()
{
    unsigned char image[HEIGHT][WIDTH] =
    {
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        9,9,0,0,0,0,9,9,9,9,9,0,9,9,9,9,9,
        0,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    };
    printImage(image, "<Original image>");
    blobColoring(image);
    printImage(image, "<Labelled image>");
}
```

Comment: Algo labels [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Comment: why do you expect all 3? I dont fully understand the code, but it looks like you start with `int color = 1;` and then in the outer loop (not the recursion itself) you increment it by `1` each time you find a cell with `img[y][x] == 9`. Why do you think it should all be 3s ?

Answer (score 0):

The function `blobColoring()` has a double loop that scans your image for value 9, which seems to be the "free pixel" value. when found, the recursive function `label()` fills all neighboring 9-pixels with the given color which starts from 1 and increments, so the first found 9-area becomes 1, second 2 and third 3. Because of the recursion, all neighbours of neighbours and so on are traversed as long as they are in the rectangular and of color 9.

Mind you that your result (input and output: C++) looks okay, but doesn't match the image in the source-code (C--). Also, change the image to have the middle area a pixel in the top-row and see how the result changes.

Also, put a breakpoint in the `label()` function to see how the variables change.

Comment: i understood, thank you. i'm still not familiar with recursion i just confused.

Comment: @Wasabi9812: as said in my answer: set a breakpoint and walk through it. Recursion is just a function calling itself. In your case, it calls itself 4 times, which is a bit more complicated, but a function calling itself 1 time is a bit as a loop.

Comment: what i want to know is ,in the original code which i post, when computer get [2][2] and find 9 after then start to calling function. then every 9 which is closed to each other will turn in to variable color 1. after all progress, where does the computer start again to read array?  is it [5][2]? or [5[4]?

Comment: now that i'm think about it. is it right to start at [2][3]? because  the value of [3][2]to [5][2] and other location which close to [2][2] is already turned into 1. so blob coloring function will just pass that point and start to call label again at [7][3]. then do the same things again and at that time variable color's value had been increased to 2. and it will be 3 when computer read [13][3].